# Display parts of a website in an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, resize

Like my heading says, I want to display a part of the website in an iframe. Here is the site I want to put in the iframe: 
[GPA Calculator](http://srm.mnganesh.com/)

I want to display everything apart from the footer and the GPA Calculator heading at the top. I want to put the rest of the content alone in my website. And on entering the roll numbers, I want students to be able to see their Grades and GPA's. Here's a sample roll number: 1021140050

I just tried this code to put in the iframe, resized it but I don't know how to show a part of it. I googled for many tutorials but couldn't find anything that could fit my purpose. If anyone could just give some hints, it would be nice, I can try to build something.

```
<iframe src="http://srm.mnganesh.com/" height="500px" width="800px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be in loading a custom css into the iFrame.  Then with this css you could "hide" (`display:none`) the elements you do not want to see from the page.

To do so, have a look [at this question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe).

*As the linked question points out, this only works within the same domain*

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution in this cases is to use jquery:

```
$('#contentDiv').load('http://srm.mnganesh.com/ #divId');
```

where #divId is the id of the div you want loaded on your page.
The good thing of this solution is that you can put exactly the part of the page that you want to load.
Instead of the iframe you put on your page a

```
<div id="contentDiv">
```

to contain your data.

Comment: <script>
$('#contentDiv').load('http://srm.mnganesh.com/ .hero-unit');
</script>  on adding that I found no change to my code. .hero-unit because it's a class. Am I right in what I am doing? Or could you be more specific?

Comment: mmm load() won't probably work then. I just realized you're working on a different server. I guess that the best solution then is gonna be the one posted by blo0p3r. Use css to fix in the iframe the part of page that you want to show. It's not very elegant but may be the only thing working for you.